# How can i do app that appears in iTunes's Apps Tab?

Tags: ios

Some of app that can add file with iTunes's Apps TabBar like following pic.

I also want to do my app like that.
I have to add and remove file in iTunes's Apps Tab.

How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add this key in info.plist

Application supports iTunes file sharing true

Comment: Yes that's right.Please, i want to know that added files's directory in Apps. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but I think you need to look into NSDocumentsDirectory.